# How do I sort and move files by extension type

Tags: windows-7

Okay so, I have so many music, pictures, documents, video formats all scattered in all my music, my pictures, etc folders, And I've just found out how to use this extension type thing instead of moving them by click and dragging the formats into each specified folder but it seems to not be working?????? I've done my research on how to do it but I have no understanding of what I'm suppose to write in the sort file.txt notepad thing, so overall I want all music formats in my music folder and picture formats in my picture folder **pleeease help thanks :)**

Comment: I doubt anyone reading this will have an idea what "the sort file.txt notepad thing" is. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry about that, I left school way too early, but its "notepad" I was meant to say, where you write down the extension letterings like all the %///// and username and all those wording texts. I just dont understand how you set out the lettering in notepad.

Comment: Ok, from what I can gather I *think* you are talking about batch files. I've tried to explain it below as simply as possible. If you get stuck anywhere just ask.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a directory `C:\Downloads` with .MP3 files, .JPG files, .DOC files and .AVI files all mixed together.

1. Under `C:\Downloads` create sub-directories called Music, Pictures, Documents and Video.
2. In Notepad type the following:

   ```
   move *.mp3 Music
   move *.jpg Pictures
   move *.doc Documents
   move *.avi Video
   ```
3. Now save it as "SortFiles.bat" in `C:\Downloads`. Don't forget the double quotes around the name while saving!
4. Go to `C:\Downloads` and double-click on *SortFiles.bat* and enjoy your sorted files. In future too when you accumulate more files you can just run the batch file to sort them into the same sub-directories.

Note: Obviously depending on what other file types (extensions) you have you'll need to extend the batch file accordingly.

Comment: Sorry what exactly is a "directory"?? and "sub-directories" could that be a folder or file of some sort?? Maybe if its not too much too ask if you could write down everthing im suppose to write in notepad.

Comment: Young 'uns nowadays... don't know a directory is (for most general purposes) the same as a folder... grumble, grumble. :) Also, I've written down what you need to copy-paste into Notepad in step 2. These will only sort the four mentioned file extensions though. Obviously you might have files of other types but we have no clue what they are, so using the four lines as a template you'll need to create more sub-*folders* and type more lines in the batch file.

Comment: okay, so I opened a new notepad and copy and paste what you told me to copy and paste, and also the double quotes I did not forget to do, then I went in downloads and double clicked and nothing happens???

Comment: But usually when I use to click and drag the formats one by one -_- they end up coped in other folders??? maybe I think theres too many coped formats all on my laptop

Comment: 1) Did you save it as a .BAT file *with* quotes? When you double-clicked did it open in Notepad? If so you saved it wrong. 2) Did you save it in the Downloads folder? 3) Did you create sub-folders with the names exactly as inside the BAT? 4) Do you have files in Downloads with the extensions mentioned inside the BAT? 5) How can files you manually drag and drop get copied to the wrong folders? You're obviously doing something wrong if that's the case.

Comment: I did C:\Downloads

move *.mp3 Music
move *.jpg Pictures
move *.doc Documents
move *.avi Video

Comment: I wrote down what you told me to write in notepad with quotes"" when I saved it in downloads, im not to sure about the subfolders part?? I thought  just writing those extentions into notepad will automatically put formats in the right window folders My documents, My pictures etc

Answer (score 0):

In `explorer` click on the `column bar with right mouse button`, select `option "*Next.*"`, there you cna find "`file extension`" or something like that..

Now if you will `click on column name in bar`, it will make a sort :o)

*(tried in W8.1), but I guess it will be also in W7*

I'm not sure if there'S some way how to show and work with extension in script..

Comment: are you referring "explorer" as windows explorer or ??

Comment: Yes :) (win + r - explorer.exe), default file browser